# Webcam initialization doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-video

I'm using the below condition to initialize the camera on Safari but it doesn't work. I noticed that the navigator object in safari doesn't have the properties `mediaDevices` or `getUserMedia`

```
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        // Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
        console.log("mediaDevices");
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
            cam = stream.getTracks()[0];
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
        });
    }
    else if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
        console.log("2");
        navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true }, function(stream) {
            video.src = stream;
            video.play();
        }, errBack);
    } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
        console.log("3");
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({ video: true }, function(stream){
            video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
        }, errBack);
    } else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // Mozilla-prefixed
        console.log("4");
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia({ video: true }, function(stream){
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
        }, errBack);
    }
```

Anyone know how to get it to work?

My HTML looks like this:

```
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

Comment: you may want to try [webcamjs](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs) because safari doesn't yet support `getUserMedia`

Answer (score 0):

All methods I have seen that access the webcam in Safari do so using flash.